# Reconstruction of shape from elliptic Fourier descriptors

Tags: fft, shapes, descriptor

I have e extracted the elliptic Fourier descriptors for each otolith; but couldn't figure out how to normalize them with respect to the first harmonic and how to reconstruct mean shapes from them for each stations. I try myself, but couldn't get any results using Momocs pacage. Need expert helps in R script. [Data in excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GQ7UdqZuWI9FuqGJjenIy7LvwZy-EIsH/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

1. to use "first harmonic" normalization, just pass `efourier()` with default parameters (ie with `norm=TRUE`).
2. Have a look to Details section in `?efourier` since this is usually not the best way to go (and I think it's very valid for otoliths)
3. feel free to contact me directly !

all the best